# How to get the remotely created actor?

Tags: akka, actor

How to get the remotely created actor?

PS:
I'm study the akka-samples/akka-sample-remote.

---

Following is the case: I have two host: host1, host2

the app deployed on host2 will create an actor remotely on host1 through the config:

application.conf

```
remote_app {
  include "common"

  akka {
    actor {
      deployment {
        /advanced_calculator {
            remote = "akka://CalculatorApplication@host1:2552"
        }
      }
    }

    remote.netty.port = 2554
  }
}
```

Scala code:

```
val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[AdvancedCalculatorApplication], "advanced_calculator")
```

The program runs successfully, but I still have a question:
How can I get the remotely created actor(***advanced_calculator***) on host2?

I've tried the following piece of code , but my problem was not sloved

```
system.actorFor("advanced_calculator"), system.actorFor("akka://CalculatorApplication@host1:2552/user/advanced_calculator")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you've followed the instructions over at: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/remoting.html

Are you running: "val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[AdvancedCalculatorApplication], "advanced_calculator")" on host2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I didn't want to copy the documentation, since it loses the formatting.

Comment: Yes, I'm running "val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[AdvancedCalculatorApplication], "advanced_calculator")" on host2.

Comment: But then you have it [the reference to it] on host2